# iOS Swift inApp purchase with Auto-Renewable one subscription with multiple device

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I have Auto-Renewable in-App purchase in my application. let's say User A with a@apple.con with monthly $0.99 in iPhone 7.

in other way user A has login with a@apple.com iTunes account in iPhone 8 and so on. so user has purchased only one subscription and use in multiple devices. How can I restrict them?

Answer (score 0):

from appleside,it is not possible.because subscription are linked to an account.

Comment: Thank you for your kind update, Any other way we can handle it?

Comment: Can the user sign in inside your app?

Comment: Yes we have login and signup functionality

Comment: You can get device specific uid after signup,and check if the device uid is equal to current device uid when appdidlunch,I really advise you to alsk apple support first before doing this,it might be not allowed

Comment: Hello Thanks for the update.Once I buy Auto Renewable one product in sandbox and  it is successfully purchased, but it was not auto renew in 5 mins (as I select monthly package). so I want to know when renew subscription will be done on sandbox environment.
https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-setup-test-auto-renewable-subscription-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchase is linked to user's iTunes account so you should allow them to use the app with all the devices using the same iTunes account. Because it doesn't make sense to subscribe two times if a user has an iPhone and iPad.

This is one of the reason Apple ask you to provide a restore button so user can restore their purchases across their devices.

Answer (score 0):

As the in-app purchases are linked to the apple account, so you restrict them but there is other way around.
What you can do is to restrict login of same account in multiple devices. Through this when user logged in on let's say iPhone 7 and when it try to login in iPhone 8, expire the iPhone 7 login using bearer tokens and other methods.